# How to document an "object" parameter of a method

Tags: javascript, documentation, yuidoc

I'm trying to write some documentation for a JavaScript method using YUIDoc. It looks like:

```
/** 
    Returns an instance of className

    @method getInstance
    @param {string} className the of the class used to create the instance
    @param {Object} options these are options used to create the instance
**/
function getInstance(className, options) { ..... }
```

Now, the options object can have several parameters, like `options.id`, `options.single`, etc.

How do I add this information to the documentation of this `@param`?

Comment: Google Closure Compiler would mark that up as {{id:string,single:whatever}} or {Object.<string,string>} if it's a general dictionary, but I don't know if this is common syntax or an extension to it. See the bottom of this page: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From reference: http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/syntax/index.html

"As shown in the example, you can also nest @param tags. This enables you to document object parameters that have their own particular nested structure."

```
@param {Object} [options] Data 
  to be mixed into the event 
  facade of the `change` 
  event(s) for these attributes.
  @param {Boolean} [options.silent]
    If `true`, no `change` event 
    will be fired.
```

Comment: Hi @apelsinapa, the link is not found.

Answer (score 6):

In YUIDOC 0.3.45, which is the current version at the time of writing, in order to describe objects received by methods you should first declare the object (**options**, in the example below) and then it's properties with a dot notation (for example, **options.url**).

```
/**
 * Describe your method
 *
 * @method yourMethodName
 * @param {object} options - These are the options you may pass
 * @param {string} options.url - the url
 * @param {string} options.otherOption - description of other option
 */
```

Comment: Is there a way to denote required attributes like this? Adding `@required` below the param doesnt work.